# Spring Data entity with simple and Mapped values

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I have Spring Data Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "price_alert")
@Data
public class PriceAlert {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private Long customerId;
}
```

So, for insert/update this entity perfectly fit  for me: no need to load entity  by id (here: for save `PriceAlert` it would be needed to load `Customer`). 
But for some selects I also want to retrieve `Customer`. Currently I solve this problem by having 2 entities with 2 different corresponding repositories. In first entity all fields are plain Long values. In second I use Mapped value (like bellow).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "price_alert")
@Data
public class PriceAlertExtended {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Customer customer;
}
```

With both `@Column` and `@JoinColumn` in entity on create I get `SQLException: Field 'customer_id' doesn't have a default value`
 So my question is about: is there any better approach to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For your particular use case. I would suggest you to look at the following snippet

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "price_alert")
@Data
public class PriceAlertExtended {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Customer customer;

    @Column(name = "customer_id", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long customerId;
}
```

Here, I have used `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` in `@ManyToOne`, this will save a `JOIN` on Customer Table until to access it by `person.getCustomer()`.

And, I have created an extra field to access `customerId` to just get the `customer_id`. Make sure to mention `nullable = false`, `insertable = false` and `updatable = false`

Comment: I've already tested that and recieve: on `PriceAlert` creation exception: `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'customer_id' cannot be null`

Comment: Ohh !! Add `nullable = false` to `@Column(name = "customer_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)`

Comment: This is because, you have `optional = false` in `@ManyToOne`, which will add `NOT NULL` constraint on `customer_id`

Comment: Sorry, tested your updated example and iit still doesn't work.

Comment: Did it throw an exception?